# Moving and flipping bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I need to transform an input number by bit manipulation. Here are the rules:

- bit 0 should be 1;
- bit 1 should be the flipped bit 2 of input;
- bit 2 should be the bit 1 of input;
- bit 3 should be the flipped bit 0 of input.

Here is a translation table:

```
Input  Input (bin)  Output  Output (bin)
0      0000         11      1011
1      0001         3       0011
2      0010         15      1111
3      0011         7       0111
4      0100         9       1001
5      0101         1       0001
6      0110         13      1101
................................
```

Here is what I tried:

```
def tr(n):
    return ((n & 1 ^ 1) << 1) | ((n >> 1 & 1) << 2) | \
    ((n >> 2 & 1 ^ 1) << 3) | 1
```

`tr(0)` gives the right number: 11, but `tr(1)` gives me 9. I sit here for 3 hours with headache and can't understand what is wrong. Sorry if this is something trivial or here is some stupid error. Please help.

Comment: To make output bit 3 the flipped input bit 0, the first part should be `(n & 1 ^ 1) << 3)` but there are more problems. Maybe construct and test each part of the or-ed expression separately.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you! I forget that output bits should go in reverse.

Comment: `return (11, 3, 15, 7, 9, 1, 13)[n]` would be a more straightforward implementation, given that you've already worked out the translation table.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for comment, but this is from the program for working with parallel port, and I worked with this several years ago and already forget what bits do what, so I'll remember this algorithm next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is giving the corresponding result of your translation table:

```
def tr(n):
    return 1 | ((n&4)>>1) ^ 2 | (n&2) << 1 | ((n&1) << 3) ^ 8
```

For a better understanding:

1. bit 0 should be 1 -> 1
2. bit 1 should be the flipped bit 2 of input. First select bit 2: `n&4` then move it from bit 2 to bit 1: `(n&4)>>1` finally flip the value of the bit 1 (2**1=2): `((n&4)>>1) ^ 2`.
3. bit 2 should be the bit 1 of input. First select the bit 1: `n&1` then move it from bit 1 to bit 2: `(n&2) << 1`
4. bit 3 should be the flipped bit 0 of input. First select the bit 0: `n&1` then move it from bit 0 to bit 3: `(n&1) << 3` finally flip the value of the bit 3 (2**3=8): `((n&1) << 3) ^ 8`

Answer (score 0):

According to your specs

> bit 1 should be the flipped bit 2 of input;
>
> bit 2 should be the bit 1 of input;
>
> bit 3 should be the flipped bit 0 of input.

your code should be

```
def tr(n):
  return (((n & 4) ^ 4) >> 1) | ((n & 2) << 1) |
  ((n & 1 ^ 1) << 3) | 1
```